# Eliminar ultimos dos caracteres de una cadena sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Uso SQL Server 2000 y tengo una tabla con un campo `rut` de tipo `VARCHAR` (ejem:'17045782-8' necesito:'17045782') al que tengo que quitarle el dígito verificador y el guión. Y no me resulta con `substring(rut,0,x)` ya que el largo del `rut` hasta antes del guión es variable.

¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Comment: que lenguaje de programacion estas usando?

Comment: @OmarMiranda la pregunta tiene los tags [sql] y [sql-server], así que creo que podemos asumir que está usando el lenguaje SQL y el motor de base de datos SQL Server

Comment: si pero dice que esta usando substring.

Comment: es directamente en la db sql server 2000

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para esto puedes simplemente usar `CHARINDEX` para encontrar la posición del guión:

```
SELECT Rut, 
       LEFT(Rut,CHARINDEX('-',Rut)-1) Rut_Sin_DV
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

En caso que hayan datos que no tengan guión, la solución anterior te tirará un error. Para evitar estos casos, puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
SELECT Rut, 
       CASE 
           WHEN CHARINDEX('-',Rut) > 0 THEN LEFT(Rut,CHARINDEX('-',Rut)-1) 
           ELSE Rut
       END Rut_Sin_DV
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: dice : El parámetro de longitud pasado a la función de subcadena no es válido

Comment: @daniel2017- Usaste el segundo código?, porque como comenté, en el primero tendrás error si es que hay datos de ruts sin guión. Prueba el segundo (y además verifica tus datos, porque tienes ruts que no tienen guión). Ah, y otro consejo, ya van 17 años de SQL Server 2000, y no tiene soporte, te recomiendo fuertemente actualizar el motor de base de datos

Comment: con el segundo codigo si funciono ;), gracias. y lo de sql 2000 pienso lo mismo, pero aca en la empresa todavia la usan

Comment: Hola Daniel. Me doy cuenta que nunca has aceptado respuesta en todas tus preguntas. Por si acaso, te invito a repasar: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: es que no estoy registrado, por eso no puedo seleccionar una respuesta

Comment: @daniel2017- si esta respuesta ayudó a solucionar el problema de tu pregunta, por favor considera [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer) haciendo click en el **✔️**, que está bajo las flechas de votación, a la izquierda de la misma (no se te descuenta nada por eso -todo lo contrario, ambos se benefician).

Answer (score 0):

mas corto que el case

```
IIF(CHARINDEX('-',Rut) > 0,LEFT(Rut,CHARINDEX('-',Rut)-1),Rut)
```